# How do I make a KEYBOARD shortcut to run SMPlayer?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to run SMPlayer

In the "command" box of the keyboard shortcut I wrote

**`/usr/share/applications/smplayer %U`**

but It doesn't work.

What command should I write to do this?

Comment: Try using `smplayer` in the command box

Comment: [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky): It works. I thought I tried this, but now I'm sure I wrote   ` SMPlayer  ` (wrong case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smplayer` is found in `/usr/bin/`.  The folder of `/usr/share/applications/` is where all the `.desktop` files are found.

If you need the full path to a file, use the `which` command (this only works with applications that are in the $PATH statement):

```
:~$ which smplayer
/usr/bin/smplayer
```

Then when you create your keyboard shortcut you use the output from that command, in this case it is `/usr/bin/smplayer`.

Hope this helps!